# Кресло или стул?

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это, компьютерный стул или компьютерное кресло? Отчего сходные по форме предметы мебели могут обозначаться различно? Проведите, пожалуйста, границу между понятиями "Кресло" и "Стул". На каком существенном основании мы имеем право их разделять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настоящее время выпускается большое количество предметов мебели для сидения. К ним относятся стулья, кресла, полукресла.

1. Основной признак для различения — **высота сиденья.**
   Функция стула — придать телу человека удобное положение за обеденным или рабочим столом, поэтому сиденье находится на расстоянии 45—50 см от поверхности пола.
   В случае кресла этот параметр ниже и составляет 40—42 см.
2. Стул имеет неглубокое (50—55 см) и узкое (43 см) сиденье, спинка обычно зафиксирована в одном положении. Ее высота находится в пределах от 40 до 45 см.
   Но существуют модели **для работы**, которые предоставляют возможность регулировать угол наклона спинки, высоту, а также ширину и глубину сиденья — это позволяет создать комфортные условия. Такой вид мебели называют **офисными креслами**, но по своей сути они все равно считаются **стульями**, несмотря на различные функции и дополнительные конструкционные элементы (подлокотники, подголовник, подколенники).
   Кресло обладает большими размерами. Глубина изделия, предназначенного **для отдыха**, составляет от 45 до 60 см, а ширина от 48 до 60 см.
   В стационарных моделях наклон спинки находится в интервале от 110 до 125°. Существуют конструкции, позволяющие регулировать это значение, что дает возможность принять расслабляющую позу.
3. Многие считают, что разница между стулом и креслом заключается в наличии **подлокотников**. Дизайнеры называют стул с подлокотниками **полукреслом**, хотя суть предмета от этого не меняется. Есть модели кресел, в которых подлокотников вообще нет.
4. Жесткость — не показатель. Современные кресла выполняются из натурального дерева, металла, стекла, пластика и могут не иметь мягкой обивки. Для создания необходимого комфорта их дополняют подушками или съемными покрытиями.

Итак,  если предмет мебели дает возможность удобно расположиться за столом во время работы или приема пищи, то это привычный **стул**. (Подлокотники и мягкость сиденья не являются определяющими характеристиками.) А вот **кресло** дает возможность расслабиться после трудового дня, занять самую удобную позу и совершенно не располагает к трудовым подвигам.

[Чем отличается стул от кресла?](http://www.4living.ru/items/article/difference-between-the-chair-and-armchair/)

Comment: По сути получается, что никакой чёткой границы выделить не получается. Последний абзац не выдерживает критики, если контекст взять пошире и вспомнить про кресла зубоврачебное и гинекологическое. Электрический стул уже прозвучал..

Comment: Разговор шел о предмете мебели. То, что изображено на фото, правильно назвать не компьютерным, а офисным стулом. Электрический стул, гинекологическое или зубоврачебное кресло, кресло геймера или кресло для катапультирования — это **особые**, специфические, нестандартные конструкции. Им сложно дать однозначное (правильное) определение.

Comment: Ох, по сути повторил вас, извините... Но не буду свое удалять, может мой язык кому-то больше понравится ))))

Answer (score 1):

Кресло (как на Вашей фотографии), в отличие от стула, имеет возвышающиеся боковые ограничители, чаще всего это *подлокотники* на которые можно опереться руками. *Электрический стул* в строгом смысле слова является *креслом* - стулом он именуется в силу традиции перевода.

И то, и другое изделие бывают поворотными и всегда имеют спинку, в отличие от *табурета*.

Answer (score 1):

> Проведите, пожалуйста, границу между понятиями "Кресло" и "Стул". На каком существенном основании мы имеем право их разделять?

Строго говоря - ни на каком. Жизнь сместила представления.
Да, есть признак, что стул не имеет подлокотников, но это, судя по всему, давно устарело.
Достаточно поискать в сети всевозможные "стул с подлокотниками" и "полукресло" - и результат будет понятен.

Помните "12 стульев"? *"Этим **полукреслом** мастер Гамбс начинает новую партию мебели..."*

На самом деле в профессиональной среде мебельщиков критерий совсем другой. Это высота сидения. У кресла она существенно ниже, у среднестатистического человека при посадке ноги прямо не становятся - или скрещивать, или вытягивать, или колени задраны. Отсюда кажущиеся непосвященному монстрами изделия "стул с подлокотниками" и промежуточные варианты типа "полукресла".

Подробнее смотрите тут. 
http://www.kreslovo.ru/chem-otlichaetsya-stul-ot-kresla/
Источник, естественно, для филолога неавторитетный, но интересный.

Казалось бы, вопрос решен?! 
Не совсем. Проблема в том, что профессиональный подход не так-то просто перенести на  бытовую почву. Народ будет активно сопротивляться. 
Поэтому я так и формулирую, что **четкого критерия для бытового использования не существует**.